# SQL Server : OR operator Not Returning Desired Results

Tags: sql-server, left-join

I am trying to select all records where the member scheduled the hunt OR was invited to the hunt. However my query is only returning the records where the member scheduled the hunt. Any ideas? I am assuming the issue is with the `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. Thanks

```
SELECT
    Hunt.ID, Hunt.MemberID,
    Hunt.PropertyID, Hunt.HuntDate, 
    Hunt.SeasonID,
    Property.ID, Property.Lat, Property.Long,
    Property.Zoom,
    Invited.ID, Invited.HuntID, Invited.MemberID, Invited.SeasonID
FROM 
    Hunt
INNER JOIN 
    Property ON Hunt.PropertyID = Property.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Invited ON Hunt.ID = Invited.HuntID
WHERE 
    Hunt.MemberID = @MemberID
    OR Invited.MemberID = @MemberID
```

Comment: add example table and expected output

Comment: Looks fine. Make sure Hunt.PropertyID is not null and Hunt.PropertyID exists in Property.ID. If Hunt.PropertyID is null, change the inner join to the Property table to a left outer join.

Comment: Why are you left joining? Do you understand left join returns inner join rows plus unmatched left rows extended by null? And where is done after all that?

Comment: You don't clearly explain your result. "All records where the member..." with what columns? If you want columns other than ID then you haven't told us so & you haven't explained what they contain. From your code it seems you do want other columns, so you haven't told us enough to know what correct code would be. You use`left join` in a way that it could & should have been `inner join`, which suggests that you don't understand either.